# What alternatives can be used to represent .NET's 'from-end' indexer expression inside a lambda/expression tree?

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-6.0, expression-trees, indexer

I wrote a mock for a test which tries to mimic a method involving any file uploaded with a ".jpg" extension and decided to use .NET's ['from-end' indexer expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges#systemindex) for convenience in checking if a file is indeed a JPEG file through the provided filename. However, the compiler complains with `CS8790: An expression tree may not contain a pattern System.Index or System.Range indexer access.` What alternatives I could use which achieves the same result/ease of use as the expression itself?

This code doesn't work:

```
_mock.Setup(f => f.DownloadFileAsync(
    It.IsNotNull<Guid>(),
    It.Is<string>(s => s.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.None)[^1] == "jpg"), // CS8790 Error
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
.Returns(Task.FromResult(new BinaryData(Array.Empty<byte>())));
```

The code below works because it uses normal indexing:

```
_mock.Setup(f => f.DownloadFileAsync(
    It.IsNotNull<Guid>(),
    It.Is<string>(s => s.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.None)[1] == "jpg"), // compiles fine.
    It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
.Returns(Task.FromResult(new BinaryData(Array.Empty<byte>())));
```

Comment: For this specific case `Path.GetExtension(s) == ".jpg"` would do. For the general case over collections LINQ could be used -- `First`, `Last`, and `Skip`/`Take`. Putting your indexer access in its own method and calling that of course also works.

Comment: Side note: you probably should use some example that is not so obviously *questionable* practice - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=net-7.0

Comment: Sadly, C# `Expression` trees have been very neglected for years and do not support many newer language constructs. Their is some hope of movement recently that may result in improvement.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I would also not that recent .Net versions include `TakeLast` and `SkipLast` that can make combinations like `TakeLast(2).First()` possible for next to last item.